# Back tracing an expression in JavaScript source code

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, static-analysis

*Sorry for the title, couldn't come up with a better one.*

Let's say we have that JavaScript code string:

```
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    className;

if (n === 1) {
    className = "a";
} else if (n === 2) {
    className = "b";
} else {
    className = "c";
}

document.querySelector("." + className);
```

The idea is that I want to get all the possible strings sent to that particular function (`document.querySelector`). So I want to get `['.a', '.b', '.c']`. There could also be multiple variables involved, modified several times in the code, so that the list would be much longer.

Now how do I do that in Python? I've looked at PyV8 but there is no documentation, so that's not an option; same for python-spidermonkey which is way outdated.

Comment: not an answer to your question, but if you just have 3 options you want something like this in JavaScript, else your results will be really skewed toward the `else` case: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % 3`

Comment: I dont understand, you are always getting one class at a time to `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Just don't worry about the JS, it's not the point

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy problem. You're looking for [static code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) to generate all possible paths through your function. Consider the following code and ask yourself how to determine whether an alert will run:

```
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
if (Math.sqrt(n) > n) {
    alert('a');
}
```

The computer doesn't "know" that `Math.sqrt(n)` will always be smaller than `n`. Without running the code, how do I determine that the alert won't show up?

In simple cases a library might be able to do it but when your function has numerous possible paths and utilizes many functions you'll need some hefty analysis to get the correct answer.

Comment: Yep, that's what it's about. I just don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: @seriousdev: What problem are you trying to solve? Can't you simply search the code for all lines ``className = ...`` and put those in a list? Because it may be overkill to solve the given problem.

Comment: No because I don't even know the name of the variable. Plus: what about `className = "toggle-" + x`?

Comment: @seriousdev: I wouldn't know a tool that can do what you ask (all possible paths generation for JavaScript). What do you need the list of classes for? Is there are a different way the situation can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could take the Monte Carlo approach: log all arguments passed to `document.querySelector` and run the code against a variety of inputs.

Comment: It would be impossible in that case: randomness, AJAX calls, etc.

Comment: If you run it enough times, randomness will not be a problem :-)